# filter using underdescore.js

Tags: underscore.js

```
var data1 = [
    {"year":2000,"country":"Madagascar","country_id":847,"group":"Economic Statistics "},
    {"year":2005,"country":"Madagascar","country_id":847,"group":"Economic Statistics "},
    {"year":2000,"country":"Madagascar","country_id":847,"group":"Economic Statistics "},
    {"year":2005,"country":"Libya","country_id":846,"group":"Demographic  and Social Statistics "},
    {"year":2008,"country":"Libya","country_id":846,"group":"Demographic  and Social Statistics "},
    {"year":2005,"country":"Libya","country_id":846,"group":"Demographic  and Social Statistics "}
]
```

This is my JSON data, I want filter it based on country, and year(unique) using `underscore.js`

Comment: What have you tried? The [`_.filter`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) function seems useful.

Comment: What do you mean "base on country,year(uniq)"? Do you want the items where the pair of `year`, `country` values is unique? That is, you want only the rows #2 and #5?

Comment: Perhaps you want something like what the [`_.uniq`](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq) method does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to select unique elements based on some key, you could use the [`_.uniq`](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq) (or `_.unique`) method. It optionally takes a callback to transform an element to its key for comparison. Arrays with the same contents compare as distinct, so you will likely need to stringify your ke; `JSON.stringify` can be used for this (or you could use `+` - with consequences):

```
data1=_.uniq(data1, function(x){
    return JSON.stringify([x.year, x.country_id])
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/honnza/xGr9e/

If you want to keep only the values with some specific values for `year` and `country_id`, this is even easier:

```
data1=_.filter(data1, function(x){
    return x.year === target_year && x.country_id === target_country_id
});
```